# input string was not in the correct format problem

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, integer

i'm going to create mathematical operation application for kids. In this application there will be only addition subtraction multiplication and division. There is a error that i cant solve and i need a help.
FormatException: Input string was not in the correct format
System.Int32.Parse (System.String s) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/Int32.cs:629)
[image: There is a full of code]

Comment: which line is giving exception?

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code as text and add details such as what your input is and where the problem occurs.

Comment: Likely `cevap.text` is not a valid `int`

Comment: try `int.TryParse` and check for the return value, if it's convertible to int then it will return `true` else it will return `false`

Comment: Have you [asked a rubber duck](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [int.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1) and check for the return value, if it's convertible to int then it will return `true` else it will return `false`

Comment: i shared full of code in text. Can you help me some more ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a conflict of data types.

> Input string was not in the correct format System.Int32.Parse (System.String s)

Somewhere your input is of type string data type when it is looking for an integer

use a parse/try pase method try:

```
int SomeNum = int32.parse("StringToconvert");
```